# Indicator Function of Pre-Image Set Expressed as Composition

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given the set $$B=X^{-1}(A)$$ Where $X^{-1}(A)$ represents the pre-image of A. Can one express the indicator function of the set $B$ as the following composition?
$$1_B = 1_A\circ X$$

Comment: Sorry yes, my mistake, I will edit the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Define f:X -> Y, A a subset of Y.
B = f$^{-1}$(A) is a subset of X.
1$_B$ is defined over X.
1$_A \circ$ f is defined over X.
1$_A \circ$ f(x) = 1 iff f(x) in A iff x in B.
1$_A \circ$ f(x) = 0 iff f(x) not in A iff x not in B.